# possible to open a mvc view and read lines through code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

im trying to build a application or a method that goes through all of the views in the project and search for a certain string "EXAMPLE_".. kinda like the visual studio search (through a method, im not trying to build a extension), but difference is that im gone perform a task when it finds one (that is figured out)

now my problem is trying to figure how to do get started to read a mvc view and search for a string(s), is this possible to do?

ill figure the rest I just need some pointers on how to get started. Anybody?
Tried to search for this but get bad results only.

would appriciate it.

Comment: Do you want to read through these views after they have been rendered, or just as they are in .aspx format on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you just need to point to a directory on the file system and read all files that end in the extension you are targeting (.aspx, .cshtml, etc.), and perform a parse routine on each one.  If so, take a look at the System.IO namespace, starting with:

```
Directory.GetFiles()
```

Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Though, if you're going to do that I would think you could leverage the indexing services on the machine if they are present to avoid a lot of IO processing.

Comment: im with it that far but i just dont know how to read the aspx file? is it the same as reading .txt files? using streamreader?

Comment: Yes, an ASPX file is a just a text file with a different extension.